# Generic XML to Java bean Conversion

Tags: java, xml, javabeans

I want to create a Java bean from the XML file which I will get as input at runtime. Can anyone please suggest me the generic way for doing the XML to Java bean conversion?

Comment: Do you have an XSD (XML Schema) file for your XML file? If so, use JAXB to process the XSD file into a bunch of bean classes.

Answer (score 0):

Typically java classes can be generated from XSD. So, if you do not have it yet you should first write it manually or generate from your XML sample. There are many tools that do this. I know for example XMLSpy But I believe that a lot of others exist.

Then you should generate your java classes. The are many ways to do this too. For example JAXB  (as it was mentioned by  @Chris Jester-Young) or Castor.